# Is there a way to call a custom Azure AD B2C policy with MSAL in .net MAUI?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, maui, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to allow the user to delete their account on a mobile app built in .NET MAUI while using AD-B2C and MSAL.

I have the custom flow built and working when called from my ReactJS website (using msalClient.acquireTokenPopup) but I can't get the MAUI app to call the custom IEF policy.

I added the correct policy as follows:

```
        private void InitializePublicClientApplicationDeleteBuilder()
        {
            PublicClientApplicationDeleteBuilder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AzureADB2CConfig.ClientId)
                .WithExperimentalFeatures() // this is for upcoming logger
                .WithB2CAuthority($"{AzureADB2CConfig.Instance}/tfp/{AzureADB2CConfig.Domain}/{AzureADB2CConfig.DeleteProfilePolicyId}")
                .WithRedirectUri(AzureADB2CConfig.MsalRedirectUri)
                .WithLogging(new IdentityLogger(EventLogLevel.Warning), enablePiiLogging: false);    // This is the currently recommended way to log MSAL message. For more info refer to https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/logging. Set Identity Logging level to Warning which is a middle ground;
        }
```

And then tried to call it with

```
        public void DeleteUser(IAccount user, string[] scopes)
        {
            InitializePublicClientApplicationDeleteBuilder();

            // Initialize the MSAL library by building a public client application
            PublicClientApplicationDelete = PublicClientApplicationDeleteBuilder
                .Build();

            PublicClientApplicationDelete.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes);
        }
```

But the delete policy is never rendered. This is in a non-embedded browser in MAUI because Google doesn't allow embedded browsers. Not sure if that makes a difference. There is no AcquireTokenPopUp in the .net package, so Interactive seemed to be the best route.

Is there a different way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the AAD + Maui samples - there are 3 chapters there, one of them is focused on B2C.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-maui

On mobile target frameworks, the system browser is the default one if I remember correctly. You can anyway control this with `WithUseEmbeddedWebview(bool)`. On Windows, the default is the embedded browser.

Can you get the SignInSignUp policy to be displayed?

It might be worth logging an issue on MSAL.NET repository https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet

Comment: I used that sample for creating my app, but there is no flow in there that I can see the handles delete user (at least in non-embedded view). 

Unfortunately, Google explicitly bans embedded webviews for any sign in related work, so if the User is trying to delete a google account from my system through the mobile app, they wouldn't be able to do it.

I added an issue to the Microsoft.Identity.Client repo. Hoping there's just an "undocumented way" to do this.